# How to move .htaccess rules/content to virtualhost?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, apache2.4

I am trying to move the rules/content in the .htaccess file to the virtualhost (file of my  WordPress website).

**Server details** - `Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

This is how the virtualhost file looks like after I have moved the contents of the .htaccess file -

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [L,R=permanent,NC]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

<Location />
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN Imagify: webp file type
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
# END Imagify: webp file type
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**My Queries:-**

**1.** Is it the right way to do it? I mean, can we directly paste the contents of .htaccess file into the virtualhost file/directive inside `<Location /> </Location>` ?

**2.** `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `<IfModule mod_mime.c>`  are used inside `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>`. Can we use it like this or have I made any mistakes?

The website was loading without any issues when I checked it (after restarting the Apache server) but I wanted to be sure that I am not doing anything wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community This question is perfectly fine!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. can we directly paste the contents of .htaccess file into the virtualhost file/directive inside `<Location /> </Location>`

Not inside a `<Location>` block. Whilst this may "work" in this instance, it's not officially supported and other directives might break (the URL matched is the absolute file path, not the root-relative URL-path - so the first `RewriteRule` is not actually doing anything, since it never matches).

However, you can directly paste the contents of the `.htaccess` file into an appropriate `<Directory>` block. And disable `.htaccess` overrides at the same time - otherwise any `.htaccess` file will override the `<Directory>` in the server config!

> 2. `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `<IfModule mod_mime.c>`  are used inside `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>`. Can we use it like this

You can, however, there should be no need to. These `<IfModule>` wrappers should be removed. This is your server, you know whether these modules are enabled or not.

The `# BEGIN` / `# END` comment markers are only strictly relevant in `.htaccess` since WordPress looks for these in order to automatically update the `.htaccess` file.

For example, have it like this instead (replacing the `<Location />` block):

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
    Require all granted

    # Disable .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride None

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress

    # BEGIN Imagify: webp file type
    AddType image/webp .webp
    # END Imagify: webp file type
</Directory>
```

In your `<VirtualHost>` you are not actually permitting access (ie. `Require all granted`) - I have added this here. But I assume this must be enabled in a parent config somewhere for this to be working?

*Aside:* I'm not sure why WordPress write the directives like this, but the `RewriteBase` directive is not being used here (and should be removed entirely IMO). The slash prefix on the last `RewriteRule` *substitution* can also be removed (this makes the code much more portable).

For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

(I also change the `.*` regex to simply `^` on the first `RewriteRule` - this is just a more efficient regex, since we don't need to actually match anything here.)

---

#### Alternative - directly in the `<VirtualHost>`

The alternative is to move the directives directly into the `<VirtualHost>` container (not in a *directory* context). However, this requires some changes since the directives are processed much earlier (before the request is mapped to the filesystem) and the URL-paths matched (and written to) are now always root-relative (starting with a slash), instead of being *relative*. There is also no "looping" by the rewrite engine, unless this is explicitly triggered. The `RewriteBase` directive is not permitted in this *context* (and results in an error).

For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/. /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Imagify: webp file type
AddType image/webp .webp
```

The `LA-U:` prefix creates a look-ahead in order to determine the final value of the `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable (otherwise this is the same as the `REQUEST_URI` server variable).

However, strictly speaking, you should still have a `<directory /var/www/example.com>` container in order to allow access and disable `.htaccess` overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!
This worked for me and I have now disabled .htaccess.

Thanks again for the help and have a great day :)